# View's correct width in XIB?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a custom XIB view and a scrollview in it. Is there a way to access the scrollview's width during runtime from the XIB's UIView class.

As this is not a view controller I do not have access to viewDidLayoutSubviews.

```
scrollView.frame.size.width
```

returns the default width from the Interface Builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a simple hack that works.

The trick is to override layoutSubviews and then get the value of frame there.